# Typescript - Is this a compose syntax?

Tags: typescript

I got this definition in my assignment and I can't fully figure out exactly how it operates and what it does.

Is this a compose syntax?

`f` is a general function there is no specific definition.
Mainly I don't understand what is `x`.

```
const invokeN1 = (f, n) => 
    n === 0 ? (x) => x : (x) => f(invokeN1(f,n-1)(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're giving here is an invocation pattern/callback. `invokeN1(func,n-1)` will return a function of one variable.

Break it down:

```
(f,n)=>whatever
```

This means invokeN1 will be a function accepting two variables, the result determined by 'whatever'. Let's look at that:

```
n===0?
```

Check the second parameter of `invokeN1` - it needs to have the same type and value as 0. Now, if it is 0 return:

```
(x) => x
```

This is what's returned - another invocation pattern! 
This represents a function of 1 argument returning the same argument. Note the `(x)` is the function signature here, and `x` is what will be returned.

What if `n` isn't 0?

```
(x) => f(invokeN1(f,n-1)(x))
```

Another invocation pattern - again, a function accepting a single argument, represented as `x`, and returning the thing on the right- you should be able to tell recursively what that would do, right?